# How to get WooCommerce product variation values

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach, woocommerce

I want to be able to list the the variation option values. For example I have a lantern that comes in 12in, 14in and 16in. I want to be able to get these values. I have been trying to use the foreach loop to get these values but I need a little help. here's my code;

```
function test_func(){
    global $woocommerce, $product, $post;
    // test if product is variable
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
        $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        // var_dump($available_variations);

        foreach( $available_variations as $key => $value ){ 
            var_dump( $value['attributes'] ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what is output:

```
array(1) { ["attribute_pa_size"]=> string(4) "12in" } array(1) { ["attribute_pa_size"]=> string(4) "14in" } array(1) { ["attribute_pa_size"]=> string(4) "16in" }
```

As you can see the values that I want are there, but I don't know how to get them to echo them.

Here's what I get if I var_dump() $available_variations;

" ["backorders_allowed"]=> bool(false) ["dimensions"]=> array(3) { ["length"]=> string(4) "11.8" ["width"]=> string(4) "11.8" ["height"]=> string(4) "11.8" } ["dimensions_html"]=> string(21) "11.8 x 11.8 x 11.8 in" ["display_price"]=> float(3.2) ["display_regular_price"]=> float(3.2) ["image"]=> array(18) { ["title"]=> string(11) "6712R-1.jpg" ["caption"]=> string(0) "" ["url"]=> string(59) "http://website/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/6712R-1.jpg" ["alt"]=> string(0) "" ["src"]=> string(67) "http://website/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/6712R-1-600x600.jpg" ["srcset"]=> string(445) "http://website/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/6712R-1-600x600.jpg 600w, http://website/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/6712R-1-150x150.jpg 150w, http://website/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/6712R-1-300x300.jpg 300w, http://website/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/6712R-1-768x768.jpg 768w, http://website/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/6712R-1-1024x1024.jpg 1024w, http://website/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/6712R-1-100x100.jpg 100w" ["sizes"]=> string(31) "(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" ["full_src"]=> string(59) "http://website/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/6712R-1.jpg" ["full_src_w"]=> int(2000) ["full_src_h"]=> int(2000) ["gallery_thumbnail_src"]=> string(67) "http://website/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/6712R-1-100x100.jpg" ["gallery_thumbnail_src_w"]=> int(100) ["gallery_thumbnail_src_h"]=> int(100) ["thumb_src"]=> string(67) "http://website/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/6712R-1-300x300.jpg" ["thumb_src_w"]=> int(300) ["thumb_src_h"]=> int(300) ["src_w"]=> int(600) ["src_h"]=> int(600) } ["image_id"]=> string(3) "164" ["is_downloadable"]=> bool(false) ["is_in_stock"]=> bool(true) ["is_purchasable"]=> bool(true) ["is_sold_individually"]=> string(2) "no" ["is_virtual"]=> bool(false) ["max_qty"]=> int(17) ["min_qty"]=> int(1) ["price_html"]=> string(145) "

" ["sku"]=> string(5) "6712R" ["variation_description"]=> string(0) "" ["variation_id"]=> int(1462) ["variation_is_active"]=> bool(true) ["variation_is_visible"]=> bool(true) ["weight"]=> string(0) "" ["weight_html"]=> string(3) "N/A" } [1]=> array(24) { ["attributes"]=> array(1) { ["attribute_pa_size"]=> string(4) "14in" } ["availability_html"]=> string(51) "

This is just for one product, there is one for each variation, but this gives you the idea of how it works. I'm also open to trying another method to get the same results so if you know of one let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use a 2nd foreach loop for the product attributes:

```
function test_func(){
    global $woocommerce, $product, $post;
    // test if product is variable
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
        // Loop through available product variation data
        foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $key => $variation ) {
            // Loop through the product attributes for this variation
            foreach ($variation['attributes'] as $attribute => $term_slug ) {
                // Get the taxonomy slug
                $taxonmomy = str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $attribute );

                // Get the attribute label name
                $attr_label_name = wc_attribute_label( $taxonmomy );

                // Display attribute labe name
                $term_name = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonmomy )->name;

                // Testing output
                echo '<p>' . $attr_label_name . ': ' . $term_name . '</p>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How could i get the product variation description, I mean the description inside the variation and not the main product description

Comment: For me, the value I need is just `$term_slug`. `$term_name` is empty.